# Adaptivecard maxActions limitation on MS Teams channel

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have a MS bot deploying to MS Teams channel with an adaptivecard.  The card has  8 submit buttons, but because of the default limitation, only 6 buttons showed up.  Is there a away to customize/increase the number of buttons which can be displayed on MS Teams?  I found this property in HostConfig for Teams:

"actions": {
"maxActions": 5,
...
}
but when trying to increase this value and set HostConfig from node js code, there seems to be no effects.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of HostConfig's only applies if you render cards yourself. You can not change MS Team's config this way.

The HostConfig defines the look and feel of a card on a host, MS Teams is such a host.

To answer your question, you can not change the maxActions on MS Teams.

Comment: Tim do you know if 'ActionSet Flyouts' ever came to production?

Comment: not yet sadly, its still a planned feature afaik

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft announced an 'upcoming' feature to address this during the February 2021 monthly community call - something called ActionSet Flyouts. See more at https://youtu.be/SEsjrFIf110?t=1178 (I've timestamped to that). It was supposed to come first directly to Teams, but I've not heard any more since then and I can't find anything online. Perhaps Tim (the other poster who's very close to Adaptive Cards) knows more.

Answer (score 0):

By design, Adaptive card supports 6 buttons maximum. As a workaround you can place [ActionSet](https://www.adaptivecards.io/explorer/ActionSet.html) in the body and add buttons in it. You can add multiple actionsets to increase the number of buttons.

Attaching an example for your reference.

```
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.3",
"actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Action.Submit"
    },
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Action.Submit"
    }
],
"body": [
    {
        "type": "ActionSet",
        "actions": [
            {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Action.Submit"
            },
            {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Action.Submit"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}